# Free MQTT brokers

Tags: mqtt

Are there any limitations ( mainly amount of messages) when using free MQTT server ( such as iot.eclipse.org ), that causes from time to time not to publish messages?

I have 2-3 device connected at home, and for testing purposes, publish about 10-20 a day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is no (at least for iot.eclipse.org)

But it is worth pointing out that these brokers are made available with absolutely no SLAs. They are there purely to make testing things like new client libraries easier or for somebody to do a quick test of an app to help eliminate a possible problem with a local broker. They can go down at any time for any number of reasons from an update or due to getting hammered by other people "testing".

You really shouldn't be using them for anything you care about in any way, if you are running some home monitoring/automation then you should probably be running your own broker (a raspbery pi will happily run mosquitto servicing many clients) to allow you to secure things properly, ensure that you don't get client id or topic clashes

Answer (score 4):

The latest actual list of public and free MQTT brokers located [here](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/public_brokers). Some of them provides service just for test purposes as **hardillb** mentioned, some of them provide even SLA for free service. Please read careful each broker information page about terms of use, SLA and limitations they provide.

Comment: Hi, shai.  It would be better if you could include the essential parts of the article here with the link for reference.  Links break over time, which would render this answer basically useless.

Comment: Also possibly declare any relationship to one of the providers

Comment: anonymous2, well copy the whole list from source is not a good idea. I think this link points exactly to one publicly editable place for MQTT community over Internet.

hardillb, yes I'm involved in one of these public brokers, exactly to this one https://flespi.com/mqtt-broker And yes we provide even Free service with specific SLA: https://flespi.com/terms-of-use But I think on pointed initially page there are other public brokers with various SLA or without it, Guy. D. just should examine it thoroughly